# Crossplatform Contact & Agenda server

Tags: server, calendar, contacts

Hi fear that I'm asking for the impossible here, but I feel like I should at least ask...

I'm searching for a way of syncing my contacts and agenda between :

- My webmail RainLoop (only for contacts)
- An Android Smartphone
- An iPhone maybe
- Microsoft Outlook 2016

If it needs a bunch of different softwares, I'm OK with it.

If I can only achieve one-way syncing, I'm OK with it.

The goal is not to have handle a ton of export/import between my webmail, my smartphone and my office mail client to keep them up to date and "coherent".

Thank you !

Comment: what does this have to do with ubuntu?

Comment: See http://www.akruto.com/best-ways-to-sync-android-with-microsoft-outlook/ and https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Synchronize-Outlook-and-Apple-iPhone-or-iPod-touch-contacts-149cbfc5-4396-4ab3-8b65-22915e4043dc . I do not know about Rainloop. Is rainloop even in the ubuntu repos ?

Comment: I realize that my question was not clear at all : I would like to do that through my Ubuntu based dedicated server, on which I already have a dovecot mail server and which serve rainloop through LEMP. RainLoop does not come in a package : only a zip. Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: OK, so what problem are you having with the Ubuntu server ?